# How does getchar() in c handle string input

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

First of all, this is not a problem nor a bug. I just wanted to know how string input from stdin is handled in getchar(). Also, is the same method used for putchar() but just in reverse?
These two functions are confusing me since getchar and putchar both take a single character from the input/ print a single char to the output.
Is there like a special buffer for the string?

working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*Is there like a special buffer for the string?*"- Do you speak about if you input the string and press Enter each character is subsequently taken? This buffer is from the terminal. You need to input f.e. a newline to flush the buffer from the terminal. It has nothing to do with the program itself in particular.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I wanted to know how the getchar() and putchar() really worked and how they handle strings

Comment: They don´t handle strings (as whole) at all. `getchar` just take a single character at each call from `stdin`, one after another. `putchar()` prints the the actual character. This repetition is what the `while` loop is for.

Comment: Yes, the buffer is the standard input stream called `stdin`. When you type something in the terminal the characters typed are added to `stdin` and all standard input functions that don't specify a file read the characters from it automatically. (Note that when you press Enter the character new line `\n` is added to the list of characters.)